# Weird characters at booting Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, boot

I have two OS on my PC: Windows XP and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

After selecting Ubuntu in GRUB screen and pressing enter, screen goes black, and after 10 seconds "^[[21~" is being constantly written on the screen, until I press any key. Is that normal, and if not, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This might sound crazy and maybe not the same thing but I was seeing this (but for me it was `^[[24~`) for a couple of days. Sometimes it happened and sometimes it didn't.

It turned out to be that the <kbd>F12</kbd> key on my notebook was loose and it pressed itself.

I fixed the key and the problem went away.